# How to control the order of UVM analysis port subscribers?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have an analysis port connected to 3 scoreboards. When a write is done on the analysis port, the subscribers (scoreboards) are called in a certain order. But I want them to be called in a different order.

The practical use case for explicit ordering is the following. One scoreboard only does logging, so it should be called first. The other scoreboard does very basic lower level checks, so it should be called second. The third scoreboard does very complex higher level checks, so it should be called last.

SV snippet:

```
sb1 = scoreboard_1::type_id::create("sb1", null);
sb2 = scoreboard_2::type_id::create("sb2", null);
sb3 = scoreboard_3::type_id::create("sb3", null);

// Connect analysis port to scoreboard
m_ap = new("ap", null);
m_ap.connect(sb2.m_imp);
m_ap.connect(sb3.m_imp);
m_ap.connect(sb1.m_imp);
m_ap.resolve_bindings();

// Write
m_ap.write(10);
```

Current output:

```
# UVM_INFO design.sv(15) @ 0: sb1 [write] scoreboard_1
# UVM_INFO design.sv(32) @ 0: sb2 [write] scoreboard_2
# UVM_INFO design.sv(49) @ 0: sb3 [write] scoreboard_3
```

How do I control the order that the subscribers are called in? I want them to be in this order:

- scoreboard_3
- scoreboard_2
- scoreboard_1

Example code on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2zQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The providers for the analysis port end up inside an associative array of strings when you call `connect()`. When doing a `foreach` on it (see `resolve_bindings()`), you will get the items in lexicographical order. This only works due to the current implementation of UVM; a future implementation may decide to use associative arrays of objects, for which there is no ordering defined.

The main idea behind analysis ports is that they needn't be connected. This means that each subscriber is supposed to be totally independent of any other subscribers connected to that port so you can't rely on any ordering.

If you want to make sure that your writes get executed in a specific order you should enforce it via your testbench structure: either have a top level scoreboard that is connected to your AP which delegates the calls in the specific order or chain together your scoreboards so that scoreboard1 does it's thing and then writes to scoreboard2, which does it's thing then writes to scoreboard3.

Comment: Having a top level scoreboard delegator seems like a mess. In that case, it may be cleaner to create my own uvm_analysis_port that keeps subscribers in the registered order.

Answer (score 1):

In the major simulators (ModelSim/Questa, INCISIV, and VCS) the order of the string associative arrays in `uvm_port_base.svh` is alphabetical. That means the order of analysis port writes corresponds to the alphabetical order of subscriber names.

To get the subscriber writes in the requested order, modify the names to something like:

```
sb1 = scoreboard_1::type_id::create("-sb1", null);
sb2 = scoreboard_2::type_id::create("--sb2", null);
sb3 = scoreboard_3::type_id::create("---sb3", null);
```

And you'll see the output change to:

```
# UVM_INFO design.sv(49) @ 0: ---sb3 [write] scoreboard_3
# UVM_INFO design.sv(32) @ 0: --sb2 [write] scoreboard_2
# UVM_INFO design.sv(15) @ 0: -sb1 [write] scoreboard_1
```

Fix on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3bf

Comment: You are relying on the fact that the connections are stored in an associative array of string index. For this the standard states that the order in which the items are indexed is lexicographic. Should the implementation of UVM change in a future release and they decide to use associative arrays of classes, then you won't be able to rely on this ordering anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the subscribers are called is "undefined"; that is if you move between simulators the order may change. Hence you have to design your code to work without relying on the order.

If order is important, make it explicit in the code (i.e. composite your behaviour into one larger scoreboard which then delegates in order). Don't rely on undocumented behaviour.

Comment: The order is currently not 'undefined', it's the lexicographical order of the full names (as returned by `get_full_name()`) of the subscribers.

Comment: Is that actually in the documentation somewhere, because I can't find it?

Comment: It's not in the documentation, but I looked through the code and the implementations of the analysis interface are stored in an associative array and indexed by `get_full_name()`. The LRM states that associative arrays indexed by string are iterated in lexicographical order. All of this is anyway a UVM implementation detail which might change, so for all intents and purposes I would assume the order is 'undefined'.

Comment: Yes, not in the documentation means it's an implementation detail, and shouldn't be relied upon. That to me is 'undefined'.